# How to get value of jquery variable into php variable without ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My js is :

```
$('#affiliates_name').change(function(){
    var id = $('#affiliates_name').val();
});
```

and html is:

```
<select id="affiliates_name" style="display: none;" name="affiliates_name">
<?php foreach($users_names as $value){
    echo "<option value='".$value['id']."'>".$value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name']." (".$value['id'].")</option>";
}?>
</select>
<?php $get_value ?>
```

and i want to get `var id` value in my php variable `$get_value` without ajax, only using jquery.

Comment: Why the aversion to AJAX? That's really one of the only ways I see this problem being solved without using some sort of cookie trickery.

Comment: Please read some documentation on what jquery and ajax actually are!

Comment: For what purpose?  Understand that server-side code runs *in its entirety* on the server, and *then* client-side code runs *on the client*.  In order for the client to provide a value to the server, it needs to make an HTTP request to the server with that value.  This either happens as a page load (query string value), a form post, or AJAX (which is exactly like the previous two, except that it's in code and doesn't reload the page).  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @esqew i haven't permission to create a new file in my folder. If ajax work can be done only this page without any problem then its okay. When i was using ajax on this page then it was not working

Comment: You're aware that `<?php $get_value ?>` itself won't actually do anything useful, right?

Comment: The only *sane* way to get this done without ajax is to make the onchange event reload the entire page with the id in querystring.

Answer (score 0):

As other members suggested, you should read about what is ajax and what is the difference between server-side and client-side code.

However, if I correctly understand what you are willing to do, you don't need any of those. If you want to display different content according to what option was chosen by user you can maniupulate DOM structure using jQuery as you wrote before.
You may find [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-dom.htm) useful. 
In a most simple way you may do something like this:

```
<script>
$('#affiliates_name').change(function(){
    var id = $('#affiliates_name').val();
    //Changing content of a Div.
    $("#container_for_manipulation").html("some content added into div according to "+id+" value")
});
</script>

<select id="affiliates_name" style="display: none;" name="affiliates_name">
<?php foreach($users_names as $value){
    echo "<option value='".$value['id']."'>".$value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name']." (".$value['id'].")</option>";
}?>
</select>
<div id="container_for_manipulation"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value
HTML tag is like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="tutoruid[]" onclick="myFunction()" value=""><input>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#check").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    alert(id);
```